# Generating States in Reinforcement Learning for a Classification Problem using OpenAI gym

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am trying to create environment for a multi-class classification problem using reinforcement learning. My understanding in case of reinforcement learning that the states should be connected to each other. Like a state `(S+1)` should be generated from a state `(S)`. However in case of classification problem the states are the observations in a pandas dataframe. It is not necessary that all the observations has to be related to each other. Since in a classification problem each observations are independent. 
In this case I am using the following code to generate an initial state:

```
def _initial_state():
    random_num = random.randint(0,df.shape[0])
    state = X_df.iloc[random_num:random_num+1,0:41]
    return state
```

My question is how do I get the next state. Can I use the same function to generate a new random number and return that row from the dataframe for my next state? Or I have to do anything else. 
I am very new to this field. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to use reinforcement learning for this problem, there are several other supervised methods for classification? Is there any particular reason like you would want to extend this toy problem to something more complicated? If yes, please give some more information on it.

Comment: To be honest. .I have been working in supervised learning. I am experimenting out a hybrid method for which I need this simulation. And I really didn't find any good documents which explains this.And most of the explanation are in a problem where states are continuous and dependent not independent.

Comment: Most of the reinforcement learning algorithms assume that the state transitions follow a Markow Decision Process(MDP) where there is some non-zero probability to get to a particular state from a given starting state. In your case, if the states are not "dependent" as you say, the probability of going to that state from any other state is practically zero and hence would not follow the MDP assumption.

Comment: But isn't each observations getting selection from the dataframe has a probability of 1/N where N is the total number of observations? So then each state getting selected or the transition from one state to another has anon-zero probability. Isn't it?